# Can I store complete user information in cookies using spring security remember me

Tags: java, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I want to store other user information in cookies like userId with username and password. I can get username from cookies when I use spring security remember me feature.

In spring-security.xml I am using custom userDetailService and I have implemented it like

```
 <http>
 ......   
 <logout invalidate-session="true" 
        logout-success-url="/" 
        logout-url="/logout.htm"/>
 <remember-me user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" key="89dqj219dn910lsAc12" token-validity-seconds="864000"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="myEnocdePassword" >
                    <salt-source user-property="username"/>
                </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>   
<beans:bean id="myEnocdePassword" class="com.mycom.myproject.utility.MyEnocdePassword" />
```

In MyUserDetailService.java I have code like

```
  @Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    try {

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    com.mycom.myproject.db.mybatis.model.User domainUser = userService.getUserByName(username);




    return  new User(
            domainUser.getUsername(), 
            domainUser.getPassword(),
            enabled,
            accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getRoleId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

In my controller class I can get the username by using

```
   String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
            .getName();
```

but I want to store other user details in cookies like userId. How I can do that? Do I need to get the user info by userDao(name) and then manually store the userinfo in cookies?

Comment: Just...don't. Passwords have **no** place being sent back and forth in cookies.

Comment: yes, but if I have to store userId.

Comment: Why do you need to store it in cookies?

Comment: Because there are some functionality like adding posts. so if user is logged in and want to add a post then I want to store userId with post detail in database. I don't want to hit the database every time to fetch the userId whenever user add post.

Comment: That's not what Remember Me is about. Remember Me is for automatically (re)creating sessions for a user without the need to enter his/her password. (User perspective: You log in once and can come back the next day and are apparently still logged in.) Ideally you don't need to care about that and only about active sessions. That said, what you want is to attach the userId to the session. Typically in a java application you have a session scoped (spring or managed) bean, that holds the user object and other data. From there you can easily get the required information without further DB lookup.

Comment: But when I store userId in session that does not stay for long time as cookies does so when session expire I am still logged in but I can't add new post as session is expired and throw nullpointer exception

Comment: That sounds strange. Usually login is tied to a session, so that when the session expires, you're no longer logged in. This might be Remember Me in effect: creating a new session and attaching the logged in user (account) to it. I don't know Spring Security Remember Me well, maybe you need to add code to refill your session bean when this happens.

Comment: Yes, that could be done like first I should check in session if the detail is not in session then fill it by calling userDao :). But I don't understand why we can't add other details in cookies created by spring-security if we can add username and role details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with cookies in this case.

As long as user is logged in (no matter how he logged in - using login form or "remember me"), you can access `UserDetails` of that user from `SecurityContext`, Spring Security takes care of it.

So, all you need is to put the requred information into `UserDetails` in `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()` (use your own subclass of `UserDetails`, if necessary), and access it via `SecurityContext`:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (auth != null) {
    Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();  
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) principal;
        ... // User is logged in, now you can access its details
    }
}
```

In other words, when Spring Security receives a request without active session but with remember me cookie, it uses user identity from the cookie to load `UserDetails` and put them into `SecurityContext` (and into newly created session session). Later you can access these details from  `SecurityContext`.

Comment: Hi Axtavt, I wanted to upvote your answer ten times.. you are great man. Thanks a lot for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there already is a Cookie! 
You can store the values in the Session.

If you like to store the values a long time, you can use Session-Passivation.

Comment: Thanks Peter, Could you please explain me bit about how Can I use Session-Passivation